# SQL ORDER BY case with multiple arguments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I would like to ORDER my results like this :

```
$query_resultat .= "ORDER BY case
when vendue = 'AV' then 1
when vendue = 'VPNA' then 2
when vendue = 'EC' then 3
when vendue = 'V' then 4
when vendue = 'SCDV' then 5
else 6 end";
```

But I'm asking if it's possible to add another condition like this :
Order results first `when vendue = 'AV'` AND also ORDER this result `by Id DESC` 
In a second time, order results `when vendue = 'VPNA'` AND also ORDER this result `by ID DESC`

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the items to be order by ID within your other criteria, you can just add it on to the end of the ORDER BY clause...

```
$query_resultat .= "ORDER BY case
      when vendue = 'AV' then 1
      when vendue = 'VPNA' then 2
      when vendue = 'EC' then 3
      when vendue = 'V' then 4
      when vendue = 'SCDV' then 5
      else 6 
    end,
    ID DESC";
```

Comment: So simple, Thanks !